# Build docker in ASP.NET Core: “no such file or directory” error

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using docker version 3, and .Net Core 2.0 web application.

This is my docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DotNetCoreWindowsTest.dll"]
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

    services:
      dotnetcorewindowstest:
        image: dotnetcorewindowstest
        build:
          context: ./DotNetCoreWindowsTest
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - "3001:80"
```

I published my web application and from the published directory I run the command: `docker-compose build` and got the following error

```
ERROR: Service 'dotnetcorewindowstest' failed to build: 
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder739115341/obj/Docker/publish:
 no such file or directory

any ideas what is the problem?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

The source seems to be pointing to /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder739115341/. Try the using a relative path instead and copy it into a speficif folder to avoid conflicts with whatever is in the root filesystem.

```
Copy obj/Docker/publish /app
```

Comment: changed to :
Copy obj/Docker/publish .
still getting same error

Comment: One more idea. could you try COPY obj/Docker/publish /app ?